# checking if a src url is working before posting Flickr

Tags: javascript, http

I am building an app with pictures from Flickr. I create pics src-urls out of the info I get from the flickr API. Most of the pictures work but some get blank with the message "File not found". Do someone know have I sort away these image-urls. I try to inspect them but find no info. Here is an url which gives this response: "https://farm66.staticflickr.com/65535/48759441527_72dbf7612a.jpg". 
Please advise!!

```
 let createPhotoUrl = (farm, server, photoId, secret) => {
 return
```

`https://farm${farm}.staticflickr.com/${server}/${photoId}_${secret}.jpg`;
   };

```
const baseUrl =
'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search';
 const APIkey = '49a691ac8b00bf41abdb43c3104e0cd7';

const getPhotos = async type => {
let response = await axios.get(baseUrl, {
params: {
  api_key: APIkey,
  text: type,
  format: 'json',
  nojsoncallback: 1,
   },
 });

 let data = response.data;

  if (response) {
   let newState = data.photos.photo.map(item => {
    return {
    owner: item.owner,
    secret: item.secret,
    server: item.server,
    farm: item.farm,
    photoId: item.id,
    title: item.title,
    photoUrl: createPhotoUrl(item.farm, item.server, item.id, 
    item.secret),
    like: false,
    type: type,
     };
    });

    state = [...newState];

    console.log('state', state);

    createPhotoPage(state);
   } else {
   console.log('An error occured!');
   }
  };

  getPhotos('cats');
```